# migration one-to-many relationship EF code first aproach

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm working on a personal project using EF 6.1.3 in LocalDb, using code first aproach, but i got this error while migrating with PM Console:

```
Post_Comments_Source_Post_Comments_Target: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.
```

I am trying to make 1-to-many relationship between Post and Comment Classes.

here is Post Class:

```
    public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }        

}
```

}

Comment Class

```
  public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Post Mapping:

```
        public PostMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.PostId);

        Property(t => t.PostId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(t => t.Title).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.ShortDescription);
        Property(t => t.Content).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.PostedOn).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.Modified);

        ToTable("Post");

    }
```

Comment Mapping

```
 public class CommentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Comment>
{
    public CommentMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => new { t.CommentId, t.PostId });

        Property(t => t.CommentId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(t => t.Title).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.Content).IsRequired();            

        ToTable("Comment");

        HasRequired(t => t.Post).WithMany(c => c.Comments).HasForeignKey(t => t.PostId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

I have two other one-to-many relationship and 1 many-to-many but seems like they work, so I don't know where is the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Only thing I can see is `HasKey(t => new { t.CommentId, t.PostId });` on the CommentMap, I think it should only have one key, the `CommentId`

Comment: I agree with bgs264.The composite Primary Keys for Comment class is not necessary.It just need one key field,CommentId.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem: key consists of 2 properties

> HasKey(t => new { t.CommentId, t.PostId });

Relationship only one:

> HasRequired(t => t.Post).WithMany(c => c.Comments).HasForeignKey(t =>
>   t.PostId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

Check this: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx